# Составной союз "не успел... как"

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

*Не успел рассказчик произнести последнее слово, как обе собаки поднялись и с лаем исчезли во мраке.*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какова будет синтаксическая схема данного предложения? Стоит ли отдельно выделить союз "не успел... как", или же в данном случае "не успел" является частью сказуемого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Не успел** рассказчик произнести последнее слово, **как** обе собаки поднялись и с лаем исчезли во мраке.*

1. Это **несвободная** модель СПП с придаточным **времени**.

В несвободных моделях нет строгого противопоставления главной и придаточной частей,  имеет место их взаимообусловленность и **взаимоподчиненность.**

Схема:  **[не успел + инф.]**, (союз **как**)

**Действие** второй части начинается сразу после действия первой части.

Пример: *И **не успел** поэт **опомниться**, **как** после тихой Cпиридоновки очутился у Никитских ворот, где положение его ухудшилось.*

2. **Как вариант,** это СГС, если считать, что глагол имеет модальное значение.

**УСПЕТЬ**, св. 1. с инф. **Суметь** сделать что-л. в срок, своевременно.

Материал дан **по книге** Г.И. Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка", 2013 год.

Comment: Т.е. Кустова рассматривает предложение с подобной структурой и как СГС? Я правильно понял?

Answer (score 2):

Не существует составного союза "не успел... как".

> Не успел рассказчик произнести последнее слово, как обе собаки
> поднялись и с лаем исчезли во мраке.

У нас СПП.

Главное: рассказчик не успел произнести; придаточное: собаки поднялись и исчезли.

Подчинительный союз: как.

Comment: Но тогда какой тип у выделенного вами придаточного предложения? По моему мнению, главное - собаки поднялись и исчезли, остальное же - придаточное времени.

Comment: Придаточное времени, да, но главным будет то предложение, с которого начал автор.

Comment: А разве подлежащее в придаточном не _обе собаки_? Или _обе_ — определение?